# How to write a program that searches through my computer for all PDF files and then moves them all to a certain folder?

Tags: python, pdf, search

I have been recently studying Python and it's my first programming language ever ... I finished the basics, and now I'm trying to apply some applications, one of them crossed my mind ... Which is the idea above ... But, I admit it I failed doing it and I have no idea how to do it to be honest ... So, any suggestions?

Comment: Well for starters try using `os.walk('/')` to print all PDF files on your computer. Moving them can come later.

Comment: So my code would look something like:
import sys
os.walk(*dir*)
print(os)

Comment: No, don't start putting hypothetical code in the comments, go and try doing it for a while and ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks! :-) ..... I'll try and if a get stuck I'll ask you

Comment: Well, my code worked ... But not as expected 
I got :
<generator object walk at 0x7f3dc2be30f8>

Comment: Look at some code samples explaining how to use os.walk.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing ;-)

Comment: You can either loop through a generator, or convert it to another datatype, list, tuple, set. Because it's a generator of your file system I would recommend against converting because it would be quite large.

Comment: I think I could make it loop through my desktop only

Comment: Note though that what you want to achieve is excessively easy to do in Bash. You're not wrang to want to do it in Python, but since you're new to programming, remember that there are many ways to achieve the same goal, but some are way easier than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked is very generic. However, I will give you certain things to consider to answer it yourself.

Python Modules you might want to use:

1. OS - For navigating through File system and searching for .pdf files
2. shutil - for moving the files from location to location
3. system - to exit the program and to take the locations from the system arguments, considering you are planning to run from command line.

I would start by hard-coding a location to a variable and use os modules to get the files in the path. Then search for .pdf files in that folder. Then user shutil to move them.

Write functions to generalize the above and move a step deeper to answer more questions like navigating directories recursively, Catching Exceptions, Passing the location as a command line argument, Validating the locations and making directories if doesn't exist, etc..

I would be careful though as you will be accessing the files system with your programs and might mess up badly if not carefully written

Errors you might come across:

1. Folder permissions for your program - If Unix based run with SUDO
2. If not absolute location (relative path), you might want to use **file** or os.chdir to change into that location
3. If file being moved is being used currently
4. If the destination location doesn't exist, you might loose the file indefinitely